# The UI thread freezes when trying to update a control with Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, wpf

I've looked at dozens of different questions related to this issue and everyone seems to recommend what I'm already doing. I'm trying to figure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code, it's really simple:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle()
            {
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray),
                Width = 200,
                Height = 290,
                Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 5)
            };
            Others.Children.Add(rectangle);
        }
    }));
}).Start();
```

`Others` is a `WrapPanel`.

```
<WrapPanel Name="Others" Orientation="Horizontal" />
```

based on the other threads I've seen, the UI thread should remain responsive as the rectangles are being created and added to the WrapPanel. But it doesn't happen. The UI hangs.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are executing the update loop *inside* the dispatcher action. It will be executed as a single action in the UI thread, similar as if you hadn't used a Thread and the Dispatcher at all. Make the BeginInvoke call inside the loop.

Comment: You may also realize that the Canvas might have difficulties to manage 50000 child elements.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the information. Just a quick FYI, the 50000 child elements is just to ensure the thread stalls long enough. As for your suggestion, I tried two tests. The first test was to update the wrappanel and only it inside of the dispatcher. https://pastebin.com/6VAJi82E. I ended up with a cross thread error. The other test, https://pastebin.com/9Sf6v1Cf ended up with the same results. Am I setting it up how you described?

Comment: You should have `new Rectangle()` and `Children.Add()` inside the Distpatcher action, but the loop outside, i.e. make 50000 `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`  calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing, I got your above scenario working without blocking the UI.

Note that I was able to achieve this using `async/await` and `Tasks`. This allows the adding of children to be put into the `ThreadPool` of the application, allowing work to be executed once a thread is available. During this time, the message pumping still occurs, causing the UI thread not to block.

If you wrap your `WrapPanel` in a `ScrollViewer`, you can see that you are still able to scroll while new `Rectangles` are being added.

```
private async void OnMainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle
        {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray),
            Width = 200,
            Height = 290,
            Margin = new Thickness(5,0,5,5)
        };
        await Task.Run(async ()=> await AddChildAsync(rect));
    }
}

private async Task AddChildAsync(Rectangle rect)
{
    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(()=> Others.Children.Add(rect));
}
```

Another approach would be to not use `Tasks` all together, but instead, allow the `Dispatcher` to switch control to process events.

```
private async void OnMainWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle
        {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray),
            Width = 200,
            Height = 290,
            Margin = new Thickness(5,0,5,5)
        };
        Others.Children.Add(rect);
        await System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Yield();
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, your proposal is going to severely limit the throughput on the creation of the rectangles. Which, yes, will resolve the UI lag issue, but will also make it take a very long time to add 50,000 rectangles. A better variation on the above would be to keep all the code (including the call to `Children.Add()`) in the `OnMainWindowLoaded()` method, but then `await Task.Yield()` with each iteration of the loop. That _might_ be enough to keep performance up during the adding, without interfering too much with user interactions with the UI.

Comment: Yeah, you're correct @PeterDuniho, the addition of adding the 50k rectangles using this method will take a lot longer. Task.Yield is a good idea, but I found that it still blocks the UI. Another approach that would work would be DispatcherYield, which I have updated my answer to use as an alternative.

Comment: Yes, `Dispatcher.Yield()` is a reasonable way to address the issue. I still think it's better for the OP to not be creating UI objects in code-behind in the first place :), but if they insist, the above is a good approach (the second example).

Answer (score 1):

The new thread isn't really accomplishing anything useful. Because the thread does nothing other than to immediately call `BeginInvoke()`, all of the real work just winds up back on the dispatcher thread, where it blocks that thread until it's done.

You could, as [one comment suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43405249/the-ui-thread-freezes-when-trying-to-update-a-control-with-application-current-d#comment73871891_43405249) refactor the loop so that the loop itself is in the thread, while the actual UI operations are not. That might look something like this:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle()
            {
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray),
                Width = 200,
                Height = 290,
                Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 5)
            };
            Others.Children.Add(rectangle);
        }));
    }
}).Start();
```

But I'm not sure that's really going to do what you want. It will queue up 50,000 separate invocations on the UI thread, all of which will definitely impede that thread's ability to handle other window messages, if not completely block any other work until they are all complete. The net effect will be very similar, if not identical, to what you're seeing now.

The other issue is that, this is WPF and you are apparently trying to create UI in code-behind.

It's not really clear how successful you're going to be getting 50,000 different `Rectangle` objects populated without *some* type of delay perceivable by the user. But you should definitely consider creating a view model type to represent the actual `Rectangle` objects, store them in an `ObservableCollection<T>`, or even just a plain `List<T>`, populate the collection in the background, and let WPF deal with creating the necessary `Rectangle` objects through a `DataTemplate` and an appropriate binding.

If you use that approach, using a `List<T>` you would just create the whole list, and then update a property exposing the list, which would avoid potential cross-thread issues when the collection is updated, as well as the per-rectangle cross-thread invocation cost.